# How can I refresh the progress of a stuck SVN repository clone on my Slave Server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I wanted to clone a big repo to our SVN slave server and wait a week because the repo ist pretty big.
Now its a week but stuck at a revision for days.

When creating (cloning) a SVN repository for our Slave Server, the progress gets stuck.
The repo is very big so, its clear that it will take a long time, but its not changing for days at revision 12606. Is there any way to refresh it so it will keep going or have a closer look into the progress?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the VDFS replication, then it's typically automatic, so there is no need to manually "refresh" or "restart" it. If you suspect that it's stuck, then your SVN repository might be corrupted or there is a problem with your network that doesn't let the replication to continue.

1. What's in the 'VisualSVN Server *Replication*' event log on the slave server? Any errors?
2. Is the network connection from slave to master stable? E.g., do you see any packet loss when you run `ping <MASTER-SERVER> -t` on the slave server?
3. [Verify the integrity of your SVN repository](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00115/). Is it healthy? Or is revision 12606 (or 12607, it's unclear from your post) corrupt?
4. What version of Windows OS and VisualSVN Server is installed on the computers?

It's hard to answer your question without additional details. Answers to these questions should give enough information to troubleshoot this issue and give further suggestions.

> Is there any way to refresh it so it will keep going or have a closer
> look into the progress?

Check what's in the ['VisualSVN Server *Replication*' event log](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) on the slave server.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!
1. Failed to replicate repository '...' with the following error:
Malformed representation header
2. From 100 send packets no losses
3. I will provide this info soon, this will take some time
4. Windows server 2012 RD2 and >Visual SVN 3.5.6

Comment: @KonstantinAfanasiev Please contact support@visualsvn.com. It appears that the repository is corrupt and it makes deploying the replication more complicated. But I think that there can be several ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks alot, i did the svnadmin verify command and it ran thru without any problems. The Master repo seems to be alright. I will contact that email!